# Mongoose Schema: object with any property name possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to define a Mongoose Schema which accepts any property name in connection with a `String` as its  value. What I am looking for is something like the following (Without having first to write any possible property name):

```
var schema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     someStrings: {
          string1: String,
          string2: String,
          ...
          stringN: String
     } 
});
```

I know I could simply use `Schema.Types.Mixed`, but that would make it possible to use arrays or other types inside. Furthermore would Mongoose lose the ability to auto detect and save changes on this property.

```
var schema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     someStrings: Schema.Types.Mixed    
});
```

I just want to have an Object (someString), which only consists of an arbitrary count of name to value `String` mappings with any name possible.

Is something like this even possible in mongoose?

Comment: Have you considered a schema like `someStrings: [{name: String, value: String}]` instead? Where the `name` values in the elements would be `string1`, `string2`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but I want to avoid using an array in order to have easier access to the properties by simply calling: `obj.string1` or `obj.stringN` to get the value without each time having to loop through the array.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to use `Mixed`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  strings: {
    type: Object,
    default: {
      string1: String,
      string2: String,
      ...
      stringN: String
    }
  }
});
```